# TFS/VS falsely flagging file as having changes?

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

When I update my EDMX file from the database using "Update Model From Database" or by refreshing the tables, a couple files are flagged in the Team Explorer > Pending Changes as having changes. These files, when compared with latest, show no difference from the source control file and I've tried checking them in to see if maybe some invisible characters were the culprit (ie, \r\n vs \n on the ends of lines) but the files consistently show up in pending changes.

In particular, the files are C# (.cs) files under the MyDatabase.tt structure in Visual Studio Solution Explorer. **There are also many similar files under the same structure that are not similarly affected.**

1) So what makes these files special?

2) Why do they consistently show up as having pending changes despite already being checked in and having no visible changes? (Rob Epstein has answered this portion of the question)

3) What can I do, if anything, to stop them from showing up on the pending changes list?

*TO CLARIFY* : I want to know why two files are being flagged for showing up in Pending Changes while the rest are not. If you can answer #1, I will award the Answer to you because that's the crux of the question.

PS: I'm using VS 2013 and I believe TFS 2010.

*Edit* I can't switch from TFS to an alternative source control, so I'd like to resolve this using what I have (VS 2013/TFS 2010).

Comment: If the file content is the same but the modified date is different TFS will see the file as changed.  It's just a bit crap like that.

Comment: @BenRobinson That doesn't explain why all the other .cs files in the same structure are not similarly affected though. Why are (in my case) 2 .cs files in the same EDMX being flagged as having changes versus the 15+ other similar .cs files? I wouldn't have found it suspicious if it was uniform

Comment: As far as I am aware it will affect any file.  Try changing a file manually and then changing it back.  Comparing will give you identical files, but TFS will see the file as modified.

Answer (score 4):

The template process regenerates the file every time an EDMX change is made. The source control logic is not comparing content of the file to determine changes, but is roughly checking the last modified timestamp of the file. As far as I know there is no way to circumvent this process.

Hope that helps,
Rob

Comment: The best way to circumvent it is to not use TFS. SVN and Git for example don't have this problem.

Comment: @RobEpstein I still don't see why these two cs files are being affected while the rest in the same structure are not. To be clear, when I update my EDMX some of the models (cs files) get flagged, but others don't. I haven't made any database changes to either of these tables/models in a long time, why do they keep showing up?

Comment: @BenRobinson Unfortunately, TFS is my only option so switching to another source control is not a real option right now. Good suggestion though, I'll edit my question to reflect that I can't switch.

Comment: Maybe only those two files get regenerated due to your changes and the rest stays unaffected? I wouldn't even bother about those files because they are auto generated anyway.

Comment: @Mathew This occurs even if there are absolutely no changes to the source code, database structure, or even the EDMX itself. Say, for example, I check-in all my pending changes, make no changes to the database, and then "Update Model From Database" on the EDMX, these files will show as pending changes. However, the other C# files will not. I want to know what makes these files special.

Comment: The source control logic does not look at timestamps.  For TFVC Server Workspaces (which is the only type supported in TFS 2010), files must be explicitly checked out in order to be changed.  Visual Studio performs this check-out automatically in order to edit a file.  The contents will not be checked in by the server if the contents are identical to the previous version.  However, the only way to avoid this behavior is to use TFS 2012 (or newer) and Local Workspaces, which work in an edit/merge/commit model (similar to Subversion) or TFS 2013 and Git.

Comment: @EdwardThomson That clears things up a little bit, but again I'm wondering why 2 files are checked out for editing while the rest remain. What makes these files special compared to the rest? I'm going to change my question to clarify that is what I want to know for an answer.